# How to return value from a function after click of a button in Suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have a button in suitelet , after clicking that it should call a function and return a value . I am aware that we cannot write that function in same suitelet,so i have created a client script and wrote the function there . I am able to call that function in clientscript, but dont know how to return the value.

```
token_form.addButton({
    id : 'custpage_refresh_token',
    label : 'Refresh Token',
    functionName : 'getAccessTokenFromRefreshToken'
});
```

How to return the value from that function to suitelet . Can some one please provide a code snippet or sample for that ?

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved in 2 ways : 
1. By creating  a field in suitelet and setting its value in the clientscript 
2. By reloading suitelet in clientscript by passing values as URL parameters.